# Fedora 22 Server on Hyper-V: Cannot reach httpd

Tags: linux, virtualization, hyper-v, httpd, fedora

I have created a WinS2012 Hyper-V Guest running Fedora 22 Server.
HTTPD is running on the guest and listening on ports 80 + 8008.
I have checked selinux - both ports are allowed for httpd.
I can get my index.html using 'telnet localhost 80' on the guest.
I can 'telnet 22' the guest from the Hyper-V host and any host on my network.

I CANNOT get an answer from HTTPD from any host on my network, including the Hyper-V host

While telnet is trying to talk to the HTTPD ports on the guest, NETSTAT shows HTTP SYN_SENT

Are there any prerequisites for accessing HTTPD on port 80 on a fresh Fedora 22 Server install?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the firewall ([firewalld](https://liquidat.wordpress.com/2013/04/09/howto-firewalld-basics/)) on the F22 server and ensure that the ports are open. I would expect this to be part of the problem as by default these ports are unlikely to be opened.

However, other things you may like to check

Does routing need to be enable on the host and if so has it?

Does the firewall on the host have to be opened and if so has it?

Comment: firewall-cmd --zone=internal --add-port=80/tcp

Added the server to the internal zone and opened port 80. That did the trick. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Don't forget to make it --permanent.